# Cant get blog name with get_option

Tags: php, functions

I am using WordPress functions to get the blog name and the current user username, I need this info to embed them on my contact form which is custom code too, but for some reason they are not working even though the WordPress codex says they are correct

```
<html>
    
    <?php 
$username= get_current_user();
$url = get_option( 'blogname');
?>  
<body>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? You don't get a result? You get an error? In your example code you are retrieving the values but doing nothing with them. Have you tried something like `var_dump($username, $url);` to see their contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need access to the property of $username to get the name

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$username= $user->display_name;
```

Get option method will return the name of the site you have set in setting -> general options

```
$url = get_option( 'blogname');
```

If you need home URL then

```
$url = get_option( 'home' );
```

Comment: Thank you guys both for your answers